# Delete string pattern in R while keeping the rest of the string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I know this has been asked previously, but I'm unable to find an case that is comparable to the situation in my data. Here's a sample of my data:

```
> head(dataraw)
   success                       2 day pre during      time observator
1:      no dry, but with some snow showers    dry 2/23/2015     JvD&OK
2:  yes001 dry, but with some snow showers    dry 2/23/2015     JvD&OK
3:  yes004 dry, but with some snow showers    dry 2/23/2015     JvD&OK
4:  yes004 dry, but with some snow showers    dry 2/23/2015     JvD&OK
5:      no dry, but with some snow showers    dry 2/23/2015     JvD&OK
6:      no dry, but with some snow showers    dry 2/23/2015     JvD&OK
```

In column `success`, I would like to remove all numbers after `"yes"`. I've though using the following line would work, but it doesn't:

```
dataraw$success <- gsub('0**', '', dataraw$success)
```

Could somebody please set me on the right track?

Comment: Maybe you can use `gsub("([[:alpha:]]+).*","\\1",dataraw$success)`

Comment: `sub("(yes)\\d+","\\1",dataraw$success)`. If it does not work, and the answer below is not helpful, please change the question and let us know. *replacing `2/**/****` with `February`* implies you are doing something more sophisticated than what you ask in the question (*I would like to remove all numbers after `"yes"`*).

Comment: Other answers might be more general/robust, but you were not that far from a solution, try "0.." instead of "0**", "." means "any character", while "*" means "any number of times" so doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
dataraw$success  <- stringr::str_replace_all(dataraw$success, "[0-9]", "")
```

This will remove all numeric characters.

**Example**

```
s <- c("yes111", "no")
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "[0-9]", "")
```

**Output**

```
# "yes" "no"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, however I don't know how. What I'm looking for is a more general expression I can use later on as well. For example, I also need to replace all strings starting with `2/**/****` in the column `time` with `February`. Would you have a less case specific suggestion?

Comment: You can use `str_replace_all` then for a more general function. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. But how could I make this work for column `time` replacing `2/**/****` with `February`?

Comment: There is no unique answer for different questions. You again can use `str_replace_all`, for example, `stringr::str_replace_all(c("2/22/2012"), "^2.+", "February")`